# C# List out of bounds exception - How to add space to a list

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a nested for loop, that adds `Position` variables to a `List<List<Position>>`

```
void populateMapPolygons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < polygonList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < polygonList[i].latlongs.Count; j++)
            {
                customMap.Polygons[i].Add(new Position(Convert.ToDouble(polygonList[i].latlongs[j].latitude), Convert.ToDouble(polygonList[i].latlongs[j].longitude)));

            }
        }
    }
```

This code throws an out of range exception because I think that my `List<List<Position>>` `Polygons[i]` is not the same size as `polygonList.Count`

How can I increase the size of `Polygons[i]` to be the same size as `[polygonList.Count]` to avoid this out of bounds error?

Comment: The purpose of a `List` is to dynamically add remove members from it, by using `Add` and `Remove`. If you want a predetermined amount of records within a collection, I advise using an `Array` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an entry inside the outer loop:

```
customMap.Polygons.Add(new List<Position>());
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll accept the answer in 11 minutes when I can